# Can the url params of the react-router <Route /> component be validated?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm using react-router (2.4.1) and I have a wildcard (path="*") fallback route to display a "Not Found" component.

One of my routes are defined like:

```
<Route path="/campaigns/:category" component={CampaignsPage} />
```

Can I validate the `category` route param in any way to check if this category exist in my list of categories? and if not, I want the router to fall down to the wildcard in order to display the Not Found component

Comment: I saw a suggestion to use `url-matcher` in their github issues: https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/issues/2286#issuecomment-158692205

Comment: Currently there seems to be only "hacky" ways to implement this. The react-router devs have mentioned that this will probably be implemented in the near future.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could validate the received param inside the 'campaigns' component? Something along the lines of:

```
class CampaignsPage extends Component {
    render() {
        const validCampaignCats = [...]
        const receivedCampaignCat = this.props.params.category

        const renderChild = (actualCat, validCats) => {
            if (!validCats.includes(actualCat)) {
                return <YourErrorPage/>
            }
            return this.props.children
        }

        return (
            <div>
                <Header/>
                { renderChild(receivedCampaignCat, validCampaignCats) }
                <Footer/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Hope that helps!